# k9s : Unable to connect to kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am using k9s tool for managing kubernetes cluster(GKE on Google Cloud Platform).

Recently k9s has stopped working and stopped connecting to k8s cluster.

When I launch k9s(i.e. `k9s -n default`) it shows me all clusters's context and when I click on one of the contexts then

Error is

```
Unable to connect to context "XXXXXXXXXX"
```

it shows me below error as displayed in screenshot.

[image]

However with `kubectl` client, it is working fine and showing all the data of cluster.

I tried reinstalling k9s and update its version but problem persists.

How can I debug the issue and fix the problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After investigating, checked logs, you can get logs location by running

```bash
$ k9s info     

 ____  __.________       

|    |/ _/   __   \______

|      < \____    /  ___/

|    |  \   /    /\___ \ 

|____|__ \ /____//____  >

        \/            \/ 

  

Configuration:   /Users/xyx/Library/Applications/k9s/config.yml

Logs:            /var/folders/8r/t5bx6ckdchjdacj3nz7qyq0b4ys7mwh0000gp/T/k9s-shubcbsj.log

Screen Dumps:    /var/folders/8r/t5bx6ckdchjdacj3nz7qyq0b4ys7mwh0000gp/T/k9s-screens-chakhcahkcha
```

Logs showed me this errors.

```bash
9:08PM ERR Unable to connect to api server error="The gcp auth plugin has been removed.\nPlease use the \"gke-gcloud-auth-plugin\" kubectl/client-go credential plugin instead.\nSee https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke for further details"
9:08PM ERR ClusterUpdater failed error="Conn check failed (1/5)"
9:08PM ERR Unable to connect to api server error="The gcp auth plugin has been removed.\nPlease use the \"gke-gcloud-auth-plugin\" kubectl/client-go credential plugin instead.\nSee https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke for further details"
9:08PM ERR ClusterUpdater failed error="Conn check failed (2/5)"
9:08PM ERR Unable to connect to api server error="The gcp auth plugin has been removed.\nPlease use the \"gke-gcloud-auth-plugin\" kubectl/client-go credential plugin instead.\nSee https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke for further details"
9:08PM ERR ClusterUpdater failed error="Conn check failed (3/5)"
9:08PM ERR Unable to connect to api server error="The gcp auth plugin has been removed.\nPlease use the \"gke-gcloud-auth-plugin\" kubectl/client-go credential plugin instead.\nSee https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke for further details"
9:08PM ERR ClusterUpdater failed error="Conn check failed (4/5)"
9:08PM ERR Unable to connect to api server error="The gcp auth plugin has been removed.\nPlease use the \"gke-gcloud-auth-plugin\" kubectl/client-go credential plugin instead.\nSee https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke for further details"
9:08PM ERR Conn check failed (5/5). Bailing out!
```

I realized it is because of my kubectl client was recently updated and k9s stopped connecting to k8s because of that.

Followed the link as there has been some changes in kubectl authentication for gke in newer kubectl versions.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke

Did auth with my clusters again

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials $CLUSTER_NAME --region $REGION_NAME --project $PROJECT_NAME
```

It worked again.